# Weird geometry is being Generated when i use multi res modifier

Tags: multiresolution

[image]

This is the Screen Shot of my model and the extra geometry. This artifact happens because of my multi res modifier. But when I try to delete the multi res modifier and add a new one all of the sculpting i did is gone. Is there any way to fix this without losing all of my sculpting . I am in Blender version 2.79b.

Comment: It looks like you modified the geometry in edit mode (adding, merging or deleting vertices/edges) after adding the multires modifier. This is not allowed and will break the multires data as you noticed.

Comment: Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Correct the currently wrong multires vertices in sculpt mode or go back to a version before you edited the mesh.